# Sequelize Not Null Error even though the object being passed isnt null

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js

Currently receiving the error from my notnull validator, however I am passing defined variables through a new object that clearly have values. user, site, and contact are all associations, so im not sure if in my api route if im not to create the properties then just pass them from my post request, however since this is MySql I do believe that it is required, I could most certainly be wrong. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Api Route

```
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Case.create({
        caseName: req.body.caseName,
        userId: req.body.userId,
        siteId: req.body.siteId,
        contactId: req.body.contactId
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        res.json(response)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Case = sequelize.define('Case', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        caseName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,

        },          
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
        }, 
  
    })
    Case.associate = (models) => {
        Case.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey : {
                allowNull : false
            }
        })
        Case.belongsTo(models.Site, {
            foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false
            }
        })
        Case.belongsTo(models.Contact, {
            foreignKey: {
                allowNull : false
            }
        })
    }
    return Case;
}
```

post request

```
    const caseName = $('#caseName');
    const UserId = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
    const SiteId = $('#insertSite').attr('id');
    const ContactId = $('#insertContact').attr('id');
    
    

    if(!caseName.val().trim() || !UserId || !SiteId || !ContactId){
        console.log('Please enter all of the Case information')
        return;
    }

    const newCase = {
        caseName: caseName.val().trim(),
        UserId: UserId,
        SiteId: SiteId,
        ContactId: ContactId,
    };
    console.log(newCase);
    axios.post('/api/Case', newCase).then((res) => {
        console.log('New Case has been added' + res);

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

testing object that is being passed

```
{
  caseName: 'tttttttttt',
  UserId: '1',
  SiteId: 'insertSite',
  ContactId: 'insertContact'
}
```

Error Response

```
errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Case.UserId cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'UserId',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [Case],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Case.SiteId cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'SiteId',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [Case],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Case.ContactId cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'ContactId',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [Case],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties in your API create method are not capitalized properly.

```
caseName: req.body.caseName,
userId: req.body.userId,
siteId: req.body.siteId,
contactId: req.body.contactId
```

Both sides of the : for the 3 foreign keys need to have their capitalization fixed.

Comment: worked like a charm, I feel like it's easy to get lost with all the syntax structure so this, like most of my issues, simple oversight. Much appreciated on the feedback!